# Angular 2 - How to get rid of extra decimals in angular binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, decimal, two-way-binding

i have such a statement in my view and the binding has value lets says 6970.87127381382131831 but, i want to limit it at 2 decimal at most. Since i am listing elements with ngFor, could not use an object to limit it with .toFixed(2). Thank you all !

```js
{{ cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier }}
```

I have tried the method below :

```js
 {{ cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier | number : 2 }}
```

Did not help me.

Comment: Did you try: `| number:'1.0-2'` (with the quotes)?

Comment: Trying in a minute.

Comment: Your method got it, thanks !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following expression will allow you set decimal part to two digits:

```
 {{ cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier | number : '1.2-2' }}
```

**1.2-2 means:**  at least one digit before decimal point, at least 2 digits after decimal point but no more than 2 digits.

---

```
{{ cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier | number : '1.0-2' }}
```

**1.0-2 means:**  at least one digit before decimal point and no more than 2 digits after.

---

About the Angular DecimalPipes and configuration: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Comment: number : '1.0-2' worked well and now trying yours. Yours has helped me well. Thank you !

Comment: So, I guess " number : '1.2-2' " fit my case better.

Answer (score 1):

as reported in official docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number

```
{{ number_expression | number : fractionSize}}
```

in your case:

```
 {{ (cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier) | number : 2 }}
```

if you want a fix number of digits you can create your own filter

```
App.filter('twoDecimal',function(input, scope){

return function(){

   return input.toFixed(2);

  }
})
```

and apply it

```
 {{ (cartitem.original_price * cartitem.qty * cartitem.unit_multiplier) | twoDecimal }}
```

Comment: I got it but as i have mentioned above, i have tried it and i got an error thats why i thought i might have some help about it. I could not figure it out why the proper method did not work on my case but thanks for help.